Is it possible for a double slit experiment to create an interference pattern at 90 degrees?
If the light diffracts perpendicular to the slits, then would an interference pattern 90 degrees from the slits be observed?


Light can’t diffract at 90 degrees - regardless of how much momentum the grating provides it does not cancel the photon’s original forward momentum.

Yes, it is possible. In the Fraunhofer approximation you have
$$
I(\theta)
\propto  \cos^2 \left [{\frac {\pi d \sin \theta}{\lambda}}\right]~\mathrm{sinc}^2 \left [ \frac {\pi b \sin \theta}{\lambda} \right ]
$$
where the sinc function is defined as $\text{sinc}(x) = \sin(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$, and $\text{sinc}(0) = 1$.
Clearly the intensity can be non-zero for $\theta =90^\text{o}$.

No but Its possible to stretch the 5 interference bars into(at least approaching ) a superposition wave packet by angle offset of the laser source but slits are very restrictive overall. Free diffraction airy beams-Laguire Gaussian beams are easier, simply dirract off a semi reflectant plastic and within these types of wave packet vortex family beams of a node one can see the diffraction potentials of the slit vertical interference vectors in a double slit experiment.
